# UIScroll View not showing UIImageView

Tags: uiscrollview, uiimageview

Ok so i have been working on this bug for 2 hours and have looked at all links i could find that also had my problem. I am trying to place a UIImageView in a UIScrollView then display the scroll view on the screen. When i try to do this nothing is displayed. so first i thought the imageview didnt have a image to display, so i tested this by just adding the imageView to the screen

```
[self.view addSubview:mapDisplay];
```

and the image was shown, but i still could not get the image to show when i place it inside of a scroll view.

Any help will be appricated.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FloorsContainer.h"
@interface FloorMapViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImage* mapToShow;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *mapDisplay;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *mapScrollView;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *mapDisplay;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *mapScrollView;
-(void)setMapImage:(UIImage *) newMap;
@end
```

.m file

```
@interface FloorMapViewController ()
@end
@implementation FloorMapViewController
@synthesize mapDisplay, mapScrollView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initializatio
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setMapImage:(UIImage *) newMap {
    if (newMap != NULL) {
        mapToShow = newMap;
    }
}           
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (mapToShow != NULL) {
      //declare both scrollview and image view
        mapDisplay =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        mapScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        //set size of both
        mapDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
        [mapScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(mapDisplay.frame.size.width, mapDisplay.frame.size.height)];
        mapScrollView.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit);
        mapScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        //set the picture
        [mapDisplay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Sci.jpg"]];
        //set zoom
        [mapScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
        [mapScrollView setMaximumZoomScale:2.0];
        //combine the two
        [mapScrollView addSubview:mapDisplay];
        //set scroll pane to main window
        [self.view addSubview:mapScrollView];
    }
}
```

It does enter the if statement. I believe it has something to do with how i connected the image view and scroll view. (I'm still a little new to iOS dev but am a quick study). Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you think it has something to do with how you connected it then the problem is probably located in your storyboard or nib file. Make sure you only have one outlet connected to each property and don't overload your outlets. Try to delete them and reconnect your outlets to the individual properties again.

Also the @properties should be

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *mapDisplay;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *mapScrollView;
```